# beforeCreate not executing when trying to create entry - Sails JS

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I've got a user model, and I'm just trying to test out beforeCreate by returning `err`, but when I do `POST /user` it creates the model fine, without executing the beforeCreate method. What am I doing wrong here? Here's `models/User.js`:

```
module.exports = {

    connection: "mysql",

  attributes: {

    firstname: {
        type: "string",
        required: true
    },

    lastname: {
        type: "string",
        required: true
    },

    fullname: function() {
        return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
    },

    username: {
        type: "string",
        required: true
    },

    password: {
        type: "string",
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: "email",
        required: true
    },

    status: {
        type: "integer",

        /*
        * 0 - unconfirmed, 1 - confirmed, 2- suspended
        */
        enum: [0, 1, 2]
    },

    // Override toJSON instance method to remove password value
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      return obj;
    },

    // Associations
    roles: {
        collection: "role",
        via: "users"
    },

    permissions: {
        collection: "permission",
        via: "users"
    },

    // Lifecycle Callbacks
      beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
          return next(err); 
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`beforeCreate` is not an attribute but a method on the model, so it should be like this:

```
attributes: {
    ....
},

beforeCreate: {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `beforeCreate` got inside `attributes`. It have to be on the outside. like -

```
module.exports = {

  connection: "mysql",

  attributes: {

    firstname: {
        type: "string",
        required: true
    },

    lastname: {
        type: "string",
        required: true
    },

    fullname: function() {
        return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
    },

    username: {
        type: "string",
        required: true
    },

    password: {
        type: "string",
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: "email",
        required: true
    },

    status: {
        type: "integer",

        /*
        * 0 - unconfirmed, 1 - confirmed, 2- suspended
        */
        enum: [0, 1, 2]
    },

    // Override toJSON instance method to remove password value
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      return obj;
    },

    // Associations
    roles: {
        collection: "role",
        via: "users"
    },

    permissions: {
        collection: "permission",
        via: "users"
    }
  },

  beforeCreate: function(values, next){
    return next(err);
  }
};
```